# Регулярное выражение: всё, кроме подстроки.

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я получаю следующий html:

```
<div>text &^%$ text</div>
<div>text &^%$ text<br></div>
<div><br></div>
```

Его нужно привести к следующему виду:

```
text &^%$ text
text &^%$ text<br>
<br>
```

Вот это я написал:

```
/<div>([^<\/div>]+)<\/div>/
```

Работает, только если между div'ами нет тегов, иначе просто пропускает.
Help.

Comment: В квадратных скобках должен определяться символьный класс, а у вас подстрока.

Comment: Можно ли воспользоваться html-парсером?

Answer (score 1):

Простейший вариант регулярки для парсинга (str - исходная строка):

```
str.replace(/<\/?div>/g,'');
```

А вообще лучше использовать парсер конечно.